# The interior of union of two boundary open sets is empty

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $U,V$ are two open sets of a topological space $X$ then  $$Int(\partial(U)\cup \partial(V))=\emptyset$$

I tried using that $\partial(U)=\overline{U}\cap \overline{U^c}$ but I can't solve the problem.

Comment: If $U $ is open then $Int(\partial (U))=\emptyset, $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PART ONE. Lemma.Let $U$ be open. Then $\text{Int} (\partial U)=\emptyset.$

Proof: (1). $\partial U =\overline U \setminus U.$

Because $X\setminus U$ is closed so $\partial U=\overline U \cap \overline {X\setminus U}=\overline U\cap (X\setminus U)=\overline U \setminus U.$

(2). $\overline U \cap \text{Int} (\partial U)=\text{Int} (\partial U).$

Because $\text{Int}(\partial U)\subset \partial U\subset \overline U.$

(3). If $W$ is any open set that is  disjoint from $U$ then $\overline U \cap W=\emptyset.$

Because $X\setminus W$ is closed so $\overline U \cap W\subset \overline {X\setminus W}\cap W=(X\setminus W)\cap W=\emptyset.$

(4). Let $W=\text{Int} (\partial U) .$ Then we have $$U\cap W\subset U\cap (\overline U \setminus U) \subset U\cap ( X\setminus U) =\emptyset.$$  $$\text {Therefore }\quad  \emptyset =\overline U \cap W =\overline U \cap (\text{Int} (\partial U))=\text{Int} (\partial U). $$ End of proof of lemma.

PART TWO. Let $U$ and $V$ be open and let $W$ be any non-empty open set. The set $\partial U$ is closed. By Part One, $W^*=W\setminus \partial U$ is a non-empty open set (because $\text{Int}(\partial U)=\emptyset.$).  By Part One (again) $$W\setminus (\partial U\cup \partial V)=  W^* \setminus  \partial V \ne \emptyset$$ because $\text{Int} (\partial V)=\emptyset$ and $W^*$ is non-empty and open.

So no non-empty open set $W$ is a subset of $\partial U \cup \partial V. $  Therefore $\text{Int}(\partial U\cup \partial V)=\emptyset.$

Comment: $why$ if $Int(\partial U)=\emptyset$ then $W\setminus\partial U\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: $W\setminus \partial U=\emptyset$ iff $W\subset \partial U....$  But no non-empty open set (such as $W$ ) is a subset of $\partial U$ because $Int (\partial U)=\emptyset.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet...Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hints only.

Consider an open set $W\subseteq \partial U\cup\partial V.$ What can you say about $W$?

Comment: W has a point in each boundary.